# Picture spanning more than one column in multicolumn layout

Tags: multicol

I like to create a multicolumn page with a picture spanning over two columns at the end of the text/page.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Does anybody know, how to achieve this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont
\begin{multicols}{4}{
        \blindtext[12]
%this is what I don't know how to achieve: \includegraphics[width=2\columnwidth]{nicepicture}
    }
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "Floats and marginpars not allowed inside `multicol'."  You can do it with flowfram, but it will be more work.

Answer (score 2):

Alas, it appears flowfram isn't as good at breaking lines as multicol.

[image: landscape]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newlength{\colwidth}
\newlength{\colsep}
\newlength{\twocol}

\setlength{\colsep}{5mm}
\setlength{\colwidth}{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth -0.75\colsep}
\setlength{\twocol}{\dimexpr 2\colwidth+\colsep}

%Note: x,y offsets relative to lower left corner of text area.
\newflowframe[1,2]{\colwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}
\newflowframe[1,2]{\colwidth}{\textheight}{\dimexpr \colwidth+\colsep}{0pt}
\newflowframe[1]{\colwidth}{\dimexpr \textheight -45mm}{\dimexpr 2\colwidth +2\colsep}{45mm}
\newflowframe[1]{\colwidth}{\dimexpr \textheight -45mm}{\dimexpr 3\colwidth +3\colsep}{45mm}

\newstaticframe[1]{\twocol}{40mm}{\dimexpr 2\colwidth +2\colsep}{0pt}[fig1]

\begin{document}
\begin{staticcontents*}{fig1}
\includegraphics[width=\twocol,height=40mm]{example-image}
\end{staticcontents*}
\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont
\lipsum[1-16]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I never used flowfram before. The linebreak is terrible indeed. I'll give it a try using \RaggedRight from ragged2e package. Maybe one could create such layout easier with ConTEXt?

Comment: I've since discovered that latex normally switches to sloppy when the column width is decreased.