# Latex three column layout: merging two of them at the begining

Tags: multicol, columns

I am writing a document with a simple three column layout using the package `multicols`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
[
\section{First Section}
All human things are subject to decay. And when fate summons, Monarchs must obey.
]
\lipsum
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

However, I'd like to merge two of them at the begining, which may look like this: [image: Random research article]

where the section 'abstract' is over two columns.
Any simple way to do so ?

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234927/134144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `flowfram` doesn't suit your needs, there isn't a simple way to do it, but it can be done. This solution patches `multicol` to shrink the height of the second column in the environment by the amount specified in `\columnshrink`. The necessary height is calculated by setting the abstract spanning the first two columns in a savebox and measuring its total height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newlength{\abstractwidth}
\newlength{\columnshrink}
\newsavebox{\twocolinsert}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\resized@col}
\newcounter{column@count}

\xpatchcmd{\multi@column@out}{\process@cols\mult@gfirstbox{%
  \setbox\count@
  \vsplit\@cclv to\dimen@
  \set@keptmarks
  \setbox\count@
  \vbox to\dimen@
  {\unvbox\count@
    \ifshr@nking\vfilmaxdepth\fi}%
  }%
}{\process@cols\mult@gfirstbox{%
  \global\advance\c@column@count\@ne
  \resized@col\dimen@%
  \ifnum\c@column@count=\tw@
      \advance\resized@col-\columnshrink
  \fi%
  \setbox\count@
  \vsplit\@cclv to\resized@col
  \set@keptmarks
  \setbox\count@
  \vbox to\dimen@
  { \ifnum\c@column@count=\tw@ \vspace*{\columnshrink} \fi%
    \unvbox\count@
    \ifshr@nking\vfilmaxdepth\fi}%
  }%
}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failure}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
  \setlength{\abstractwidth}{2\linewidth}
  \addtolength{\abstractwidth}{\columnsep}
  \savebox{\twocolinsert}{\begin{minipage}{\abstractwidth}
      \section*{Abstract}
      \lipsum[1]
  \end{minipage}}
  \setlength{\columnshrink}{\ht\twocolinsert}
  \addtolength{\columnshrink}{\dp\twocolinsert}
  \noindent\usebox{\twocolinsert}

  \section*{Introduction}
  \lipsum[2-10]
  \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This patch no longer works with TeX Live 2022 with the latest package of `multicol`.